# Is there a way in SAS to run the same set of procedures on multiple datasets?

Tags: sas

I have about 10 datasets in the rawMed library that I want to run this bit of code that creates copies of all the variables, joins them to old dataset and outputs a new dataset. Is there a way to incorporate this into a loop to create these new tables without copying and pasting 10 times? I'd also like to create the list of tables automatically since new ones may be added in the future that will also require duplication.

( I cannot merge all tables first and run a single proc transpose because the resulting table errors out since it would have approx 2,000 columns)

```
proc sort data= rawMed.mr1982;
by MRFORM MedReportID;
run;
proc transpose data=rawMed.mr1982 out=long_mr1982 (rename=(col1=rawValue ));
by   MRFORM MedReportID;
var _all_;
run;

data want_long;
set long_mr1982 ;
newTXDT = rawValue;
run;

proc transpose
  data=want_long
  out=want_wide(drop=_name_ )
  suffix=_new let;
by MRFORM MedReportID ;
id _NAME_;
var newTXDT;
run;`

proc sql;
create table final.f_mr1982 as
select 
a.*
,b.*

from rawmed.mr1982 as a
left join want_wide as b on a.mrform=b.mrform and a.MedReportID=b.MedReportID
;
quit;
```

Comment: For sure, usually you use macros. Something to think about though, is how to unique define your output data sets for each iteration. https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Comment: How would the list of tables be defined? Is it all tables in the rawMed library? Everything with the prefix MR? A specific set of years? If it's years a macro loop may be a better option. If you want to combine all ten data sets at the end, the join may be easier as a data step as well.

Comment: Is this your actual code? It seems a bit redundant in places and merging a transpose data back with itself is weird. Can you show the actual data and explain more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, it's my actual code. It probably is redundant at places and I'm sure there are more efficient ways to code this. I'm not that skilled yet. the tables are all in the rawMed library and have the same naming convention. (mr1982 .... up to mr 2019). There are about 10 of them. They are different form versions of a medical report that has changed over the years. the data that was collected on different versions also changed over the years. I need to create new, standardized /formatted variables were applicable while still retaining copies the raw variables and values

Comment: Originally, I was going to have one giant merged table with all the raw variables AND all the new copies across all of the form versions, but I think now I'm going to have them in two separate tables. One merged dataset with all the raw variables & values, and a second merged dataset with copies to perform all the standardization. I'll be dropping lots of the variables after I consolidate. ( ex. How the date of the incident was collected changed on the versions. there will be a new variable IncidentDateTime_new which will combined data from IncDate, IncTime, IncDay, IncMon, IncYear and Inc)

Comment: Does not sound like a task that needs either macro code or PROC TRANSPOSE.  Just figure out the renames/recodes you need to perform and write the data step to generate the analysis dataset from the original 10 datasets.

Answer (score 0):

This is inefficient but works.

- Create a macro that takes two parameters, your start and end year
- Use a do loop to loop between the parameters
- Replace all instances of the year (1982) in your data set with the macro variable.
- delete any intermediary data sets that are not uniquely named

```
%macro loop(yr_start = , yr_end = );

%do yr=&yr_start %to &yr_end.;

proc sort data= rawMed.mr&yr.;
by MRFORM MedReportID;
run;

proc transpose data=rawMed.mr&yr. out=long_mr&yr. (rename=(col1=newtxdt));
by   MRFORM MedReportID;
var _all_;
run;


proc transpose
  data=long_mr&yr.
  out=want_wide(drop=_name_ )
  suffix=_new let;
by MRFORM MedReportID ;
id _NAME_;
var newTXDT;
run;`

proc sql;
create table final.f_mr&yr. as
select 
a.*
,b.*

from rawmed.mr&yr. as a
left join want_wide as b on a.mrform=b.mrform and a.MedReportID=b.MedReportID
;
quit;

*delete want_wide so it does not exist in next loop in case something goes wrong;
proc datasets lib=work nodetails nolist;
delete want_wide;
quit;

%end;

%mend;

*call the macro;
%loop(yr_start = 1982, yr_end = 2019);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create copies of each variable and retain all their properties (formats, lengths, labels, etc) there are better ways.

Consider the following macro that cojoins a data set.  Then use the macro for your 10 data sets:

```
%cojoin (data=rawMed.mr1982, ignore=MRFORM MedReportID, out=final.f_mr1982)
%cojoin (data=rawMed.mr1983, ignore=MRFORM MedReportID, out=final.f_mr1983)
...
%cojoin (data=rawMed.mr1989, ignore=MRFORM MedReportID, out=final.f_mr1989)
```

```
%macro cojoin(data=, keep=_all_, ignore=, suffix=_new, out=);

  /* pass 1 get names of variables to cojoin */

  proc contents noprint data=&data(keep=&keep drop=&ignore) out=_c_;
  run;

  /* codegen rename and assignment statments */
  proc sql noprint;
    select 
      cats (name,'=',name,"&suffix")
    , cats (name,"&suffix",'=',name)
    into
      :renames separated by ' ' 
    , :assignments separated by ';'
    from _c_;

    %put &renames;

  /* pass 2 cojoin each record with assignments */
  data &out;
    set &data &data(rename=(&renames) obs=0);
    &assignments;
  run;

  proc delete data=_c_;
  run; 
%mend;
```

Usage example:

```
options mprint;

%cojoin(data=sashelp.cars, ignore=make model, out=work.want);
```

Log

```
MPRINT(COJOIN):   data work.want;
MPRINT(COJOIN):   set sashelp.cars sashelp.cars(rename=(Cylinders=Cylinders_new DriveTrain=DriveTrain_new EngineSize=EngineSize_new
Horsepower=Horsepower_new Invoice=Invoice_new Length=Length_new MPG_City=MPG_City_new MPG_Highway=MPG_Highway_new MSRP=MSRP_new
Origin=Origin_new Type=Type_new Weight=Weight_new Wheelbase=Wheelbase_new) obs=0);
MPRINT(COJOIN):   Cylinders_new=Cylinders;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  DriveTrain_new=DriveTrain;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  EngineSize_new=EngineSize;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  Horsepower_new=Horsepower;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  Invoice_new=Invoice;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  Length_new=Length;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  MPG_City_new=MPG_City;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  MPG_Highway_new=MPG_Highway;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  MSRP_new=MSRP;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  Origin_new=Origin;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  Type_new=Type;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  Weight_new=Weight;
MPRINT(COJOIN):  Wheelbase_new=Wheelbase;
MPRINT(COJOIN):   run;
```